# while deployment of MVC 4 web api project API's are not found by the browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created MVC 4 project and i am deploying the application on server 2008 and it when we run the application, in firebug and IE console we are receiving the error 404 Not Found. can you suggest what we can do to resolve the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have hardcoded the url to your Web API in your javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/session/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ...
    });

</script>
```

instead of using an url helper to generate the url to this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "session", action = "login" })',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ...
    });

</script>
```

The reason you need to use url helpers is because when you deploy your application in IIS you might deploy it in a virtual directory, so the correct location of your API is now `someappname/api/session/login` instead of only `/api/session/login`. If you use an url helper, it will take into account the virtual directory name.